# input many strings in a single line into a vector ? (C++)

Tags: c++, string, vector, line, cin

*I am trying to get the following words entered in a single line,into a vector :*

```
int n=0,c=0,f=1;

    cin >> n >> c >> f;
    graph_t g(n);
    vector < vector <string> > hashtable;
    vector <string> hobbies;

    for( int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    { cout<< i <<endl;
        for( int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            cout<< j <<endl;
            string moo;
            cin >> moo;
            hobbies.push_back(moo);
        }

        sort(hobbies.begin(),hobbies.end());

        hashtable.push_back(hobbies);
    }
```

**my input is :**

```
4 3 1
hello hai moo
//(i need to be able to enter3 more lines of similar words,but I cant the program terminates)
```

**my input should be:**

```
4 3 1
hello hai moo
hai ohh hola
oooh hello cii
zzzz meow cii
```

*But it doesnt take input after the second line? Should I use something else other than cin?*

Comment: Unrelated, but was it your intention to have all words *for all lines* accumulate in `hobbies` ? (ie. each `hobbies` you push will have every word in all previous lines of input file due to the scope of `hobbies` decl).

Comment: i dont really undertand what you are saying.but yes I am required to input all the words in one line.

Comment: The more I look at it, the more it seems a ginormous **[XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)**. What are you trying to achieve? If you're trying to build a graph from text input, please... just say it! I've quite a few answers doing precisely that, and no doubt I can whip up what you want. But your code sample is cryptic, and it doesn't fail for the input specified either: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0330064f51796992

Comment: I edited my question, It was my mistake I did not comment in the input,now it should be clearer, yes,it is input to graph,before inputing to graph i take characteristics of various students in each line and compare them,for that I need each word to be stored in a vector entry,it works for some people the way ive done it above,it doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 2):

In the interest of overkill:

```
int main() {
    using namespace boost::spirit::karma;
    std::cout << format_delimited(columns(3) [ *auto_ ], ' ', boost::make_iterator_range(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin), {}));
}
```

Prints input words in 3 columns:

```
4 3 1 
hello hai moo 
(i need to 
be able to 
enter3 more lines 
of similar words,but 
I cant the 
program terminates)
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d39bb1af6b33b9cd)**

Note that comma is not considered a separator.

Comment: If i use this,I can store each words seperated by spaces in a vector?

Comment: @LoveMeow in that case I'd use Spirit Qi (parsing): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34716611e3685004

Comment: Wait, do you not want to groups of 3 words? If you just wanted to copy the input strings: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e9b448c4a10c86f

Comment: Sorry if its a stupid question,but I don't understand,shudn't it work without an iterator just fine?

Comment: What should work? And what would it do if it "worked"? I see you've updated the question. Let me look at it now

Comment: The way its done in the question, it has worked fine before,I used to be able to take spaced strings in one line, and store them in a vector the same way, now it just quits after the first line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65909/discussion-between-sehe-and-lovemeow).

Answer (score 0):

Adding the header `#include <climits>` solved the problem, I also cleaned my project in eclipse.